# How should an WCF receiver service monitor an MSMQ queue and service requests in a real-world environment?

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq, distributed

I have a service that queues requests in MSMQ. On the other side I have a WCF service that can handle those requests. How can I have the WCF receiver service respond when messages are available on the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the netMsmqBinding or the msmqIntegrationBinding?

Then your service method will automatically be called when a message is placed on the queue.

To ensure this, your OperationContract should look similar to this:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
void HandleMyMessage (MsmqMessage<String> message);
```

Hope this helps some